# Bug in Contour Plot

Tags: plotting

I think the following are bugs:

`ContourPlot[y (x - 1)^2 == 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 10}]`

[image]

`ContourPlot[Exp[-y]*(x - 1)^2 == 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 10}]`

[image]

Please note that I'm not refering to the lack of resolution. I'm talking about the fact that there should be a vertical line $x=1$.

It seems the problem is due to the $(x-1)^2$ term, since without the square, it works fine.

Comment: why you set them functions == 0 i think you don't need to do this

Comment: Do not use the bugs tag for unconfirmed potential bugs.
Add `PlotRange` to your example. Observe.

Comment: @ciao I've just added `PlotRange` and varied xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax, but I don't observe any modification...